# What could be causing http 500 error on Godaddy shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I created a simple website with using ASP.NET MVC. There is only one controller, the Home Controller. It serves up single page which has a contact form which uses an Axios post to send the form to the SendEmail method/endpoint.

```
[HttpPost]
        public bool SendEmail(Contact contact)
        {
           ....
        }
```

The client side call

```
axios.post(_url, {

            Name:       document.getElementById('name').value,
            Phone:      document.getElementById('phone').value,
            Email:      document.getElementById('email').value,
            Message:    document.getElementById('message').value,
            CanText:    canTxt



    })
```

Everything works fine locally. However when I publish to Godaddy, I get an Http 500 error. I think my web.config is correct. Can anyone else think of a possible issue or do I need to take this up with Godaddy?

```
 <system.web>
    <trust level="Full"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.codedom>

  </system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling detailed errors in your web.config?  This is what GoDaddy recommends for 500 errors on pages hosted on their site.  Here is a link to their support article:

[GoDaddy support--enabling custom errors](https://www.godaddy.com/help/common-web-page-errors-2505)

You might also look for the location of server logs, if available to you.  You'll often find more detailed info in the logs.  Most of what I find online is for GoDaddy's Linux control panel, and I think you're (obviously) hosted on Windows, so you might need to dig a little to find if/where your server logs are, or if they're accessible to you.  But the concept remains the same.